# text tag not rendering inside a link tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, eleventy

I want to use text tags inside svg as links but wrapping them inside an `a` tag seems to make them unable to render. here is the html

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="819"
  height="673" viewBox="0,0,819,673" class="w-full">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000100" stroke-width="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter"
stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none"
font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
<path d="M409.5,319.17949l50,17.32051" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M459.5,336.5l-77.79645,67.3737" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M459.5,336.5l-77.79645,67.3737" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M381.70355,403.8737l-25.11858,-130.51996" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M381.70355,403.8737l-25.11858,-130.51996" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M356.58497,273.35373l153.94023,53.32646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M356.58497,273.35373l153.94023,53.32646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M510.5252,326.68019l-145.83005,126.29253" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M510.5252,326.68019l-145.83005,126.29253" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M364.69515,452.97272l-42.12698,-218.89821" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M364.69515,452.97272l-42.12698,-218.89821" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M322.56817,234.07451l238.98224,82.78588" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>

<a href="writings" target="_blank">
  <text x="-402.27378" y="272.51973" transform="rotate(-100.89339)" fill="#000100"
    stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24"
    text-anchor="middle">WRITINGS</text>
</a>

<path d="M322.56817,234.07451l238.98224,82.78588" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M561.55041,316.86039l-213.86366,185.21136" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>

<a href="projects" target="_blank">
  <text x="507.87466" y="115.59441" transform="rotate(19.10661)" fill="#000100"
    stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24"
    text-anchor="middle">PROJECTS</text>
</a>

<path d="M561.55041,316.86039l-213.86366,185.21136" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M347.68675,502.07175l-59.13538,-307.27646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M347.68675,502.07175l-59.13538,-307.27646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M288.55137,194.79529l324.02424,112.24529" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M288.55137,194.79529l324.02424,112.24529" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M612.57561,307.04058l-281.89726,244.13019" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M612.57561,307.04058l-281.89726,244.13019" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M330.67835,551.17078l-76.14378,-395.6547" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>

<a href="github" target="_blank"><text x="-75.60088" y="-633.12574" transform="rotate(139.10661)" fill="#000100"
    stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24"
    text-anchor="middle">GITHUB</text></a>

<path d="M330.67835,551.17078l-76.14378,-395.6547" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M254.53457,155.51607l409.06625,141.70471" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M254.53457,155.51607l409.06625,141.70471" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M663.60082,297.22078l-349.93087,303.04902" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M663.60082,297.22078l-349.93087,303.04902" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M313.66995,600.2698l-93.15218,-484.03295" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M313.66995,600.2698l-93.15218,-484.03295" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M220.51776,116.23685l494.10826,171.16412" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M220.51776,116.23685l494.10826,171.16412" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M714.62602,287.40097l-417.96447,361.96785" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M714.62602,287.40097l-417.96447,361.96785" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M296.66155,649.36883l-110.16059,-572.41119" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M296.66155,649.36883l-110.16059,-572.41119" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M186.50096,76.95763l579.15026,200.62354" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M186.50096,76.95763l579.15026,200.62354" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M765.65122,277.58117l-485.99808,420.88668" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M765.65122,277.58117l-485.99808,420.88668" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
<path d="M279.65314,698.46785l-127.16899,-660.78944" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'll  want to update your snippet to not even bother with all those paths that aren't contributing to the problem, and then also properly indent the SVG itself. Additionally, please update your post to explain whether you're using this as standalone, or embedded in an HTML element because that makes quite a big difference.

Comment: The text falls outside the SVG canvas. Also many of the paths since you have an svg element with no viewBox and the default size is 300/150

Comment: Please try using <svg viewBox="150 30 620 670"> instead.

Comment: @enxaneta my bad, there was an svg tag wrapping this and having the viewbox attribute, i will edit the question to reflect it

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry about that, ive made some changes to the question. the svg is in an html document but is not wrapped by any tags

Comment: i realised that the real problem was me trying to modify the svg through js after the page loads, and inserting `a` tags that way.

Comment: if the SVG is in an HTML document, it is wrapped by html tags, because it'll want to have `<!doctype html><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>` around it. Also not that when used in an HTML document, you don't indicate XML namespaces (because you're not in XML) and the `xlink` mechanism is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like one of the comments say, you should add the attribute `viewBox` to `<svg>`:

```html
<svg viewBox="150 30 620 670">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000100" stroke-width="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
  <path d="M409.5,319.17949l50,17.32051" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M459.5,336.5l-77.79645,67.3737" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M459.5,336.5l-77.79645,67.3737" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M381.70355,403.8737l-25.11858,-130.51996" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M381.70355,403.8737l-25.11858,-130.51996" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M356.58497,273.35373l153.94023,53.32646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M356.58497,273.35373l153.94023,53.32646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M510.5252,326.68019l-145.83005,126.29253" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M510.5252,326.68019l-145.83005,126.29253" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M364.69515,452.97272l-42.12698,-218.89821" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M364.69515,452.97272l-42.12698,-218.89821" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M322.56817,234.07451l238.98224,82.78588" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <a href="WRITINGS" target="_blank">
  <text x="-402.27378" y="272.51973" transform="rotate(-100.89339)" fill="#000100" stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24" text-anchor="middle">
  <tspan>WRITINGS</tspan></text></a>
  <path d="M322.56817,234.07451l238.98224,82.78588" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M561.55041,316.86039l-213.86366,185.21136" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <a href="PROJECTS" target="_blank">
  <text x="507.87466" y="115.59441" transform="rotate(19.10661)" fill="#000100" stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24" text-anchor="middle">
  <tspan>PROJECTS</tspan></text></a>
  <path d="M561.55041,316.86039l-213.86366,185.21136" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M347.68675,502.07175l-59.13538,-307.27646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M347.68675,502.07175l-59.13538,-307.27646" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M288.55137,194.79529l324.02424,112.24529" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M288.55137,194.79529l324.02424,112.24529" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M612.57561,307.04058l-281.89726,244.13019" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M612.57561,307.04058l-281.89726,244.13019" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M330.67835,551.17078l-76.14378,-395.6547" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <a href="GITHUB" target="_blank">
  <text x="-75.60088" y="-633.12574" transform="rotate(139.10661)" fill="#000100" stroke-width="0.1" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" font-size="24" text-anchor="middle">
  <tspan>GITHUB</tspan></text></a>
  <path d="M330.67835,551.17078l-76.14378,-395.6547" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M254.53457,155.51607l409.06625,141.70471" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M254.53457,155.51607l409.06625,141.70471" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M663.60082,297.22078l-349.93087,303.04902" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M663.60082,297.22078l-349.93087,303.04902" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M313.66995,600.2698l-93.15218,-484.03295" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M313.66995,600.2698l-93.15218,-484.03295" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M220.51776,116.23685l494.10826,171.16412" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M220.51776,116.23685l494.10826,171.16412" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M714.62602,287.40097l-417.96447,361.96785" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M714.62602,287.40097l-417.96447,361.96785" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M296.66155,649.36883l-110.16059,-572.41119" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M296.66155,649.36883l-110.16059,-572.41119" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M186.50096,76.95763l579.15026,200.62354" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M186.50096,76.95763l579.15026,200.62354" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M765.65122,277.58117l-485.99808,420.88668" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M765.65122,277.58117l-485.99808,420.88668" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  <path d="M279.65314,698.46785l-127.16899,-660.78944" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

I also made an alternate solution of the entire SVG. Here I just use `<line>` and `<g>` to make the triangle. I think it must be easier to control -- like how mush it should rotate etc.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" width="400">
  <g fill="#000100" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000100" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" font-variant="small-caps" text-anchor="middle" >
    <g transform="translate(100 100) rotate(20)">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0"/>
      <g transform="translate(10 0) rotate(120)">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="0"/>
        <g transform="translate(20 0) rotate(120)">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0"/>
          <g transform="translate(30 0) rotate(120)">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="40" y2="0"/>
            <g transform="translate(40 0) rotate(120)">
              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0"/>
              <g transform="translate(50 0) rotate(120)">
                <a href="WRITINGS" target="_blank">
                  <text transform="translate(30 0)" stroke="none">Writings</text>
                </a>
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="60" y2="0"/>
                <g transform="translate(60 0) rotate(120)">
                  <a href="PROJECTS" target="_blank">
                    <text transform="translate(35 0)" stroke="none">Projects</text>
                  </a>
                  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="70" y2="0"/>
                  <g transform="translate(70 0) rotate(120)">
                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="80" y2="0"/>
                    <g transform="translate(80 0) rotate(120)">
                      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="90" y2="0"/>
                      <g transform="translate(90 0) rotate(120)">
                        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0"/>
                        <g transform="translate(100 0) rotate(120)">
                          <a href="GITHUB" target="_blank">
                            <text transform="translate(55 0)" stroke="none">Github</text>
                          </a>
                          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="110" y2="0"/>
                          <g transform="translate(110 0) rotate(120)">
                            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="120" y2="0"/>
                            <g transform="translate(120 0) rotate(120)">
                              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="130" y2="0"/>
                              <g transform="translate(130 0) rotate(120)">
                                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="140" y2="0"/>
                                <g transform="translate(140 0) rotate(120)">
                                  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="150" y2="0"/>
                                  <g transform="translate(150 0) rotate(120)">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="160" y2="0"/>
                                    <g transform="translate(160 0) rotate(120)">
                                      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="170" y2="0"/>
                                      <g transform="translate(170 0) rotate(120)">
                                        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="180" y2="0"/>
                                        <g transform="translate(180 0) rotate(120)">
                                          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="190" y2="0"/>
                                          <g transform="translate(190 0) rotate(120)">
                                            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="0"/>
                                            <g transform="translate(200 0) rotate(120)">
                                              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="210" y2="0"/>
                                            </g>
                                          </g>
                                        </g>
                                      </g>
                                    </g>
                                  </g>
                                </g>
                              </g>
                            </g>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for the alternate solution :) i realised that the real mistake i was making tho is editing the svg through js after the page loads

Answer (score 0):

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" width="400">
  <g fill="#000100" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000100" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" font-variant="small-caps" text-anchor="middle" >
    <g transform="translate(100 100) rotate(20)">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0"/>
      <g transform="translate(10 0) rotate(120)">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="0"/>
        <g transform="translate(20 0) rotate(120)">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0"/>
          <g transform="translate(30 0) rotate(120)">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="40" y2="0"/>
            <g transform="translate(40 0) rotate(120)">
              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0"/>
              <g transform="translate(50 0) rotate(120)">
                <a href="WRITINGS" target="_blank">
                  <text transform="translate(30 0)" stroke="none">Writings</text>
                </a>
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="60" y2="0"/>
                <g transform="translate(60 0) rotate(120)">
                  <a href="PROJECTS" target="_blank">
                    <text transform="translate(35 0)" stroke="none">Projects</text>
                  </a>
                  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="70" y2="0"/>
                  <g transform="translate(70 0) rotate(120)">
                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="80" y2="0"/>
                    <g transform="translate(80 0) rotate(120)">
                      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="90" y2="0"/>
                      <g transform="translate(90 0) rotate(120)">
                        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0"/>
                        <g transform="translate(100 0) rotate(120)">
                          <a href="GITHUB" target="_blank">
                            <text transform="translate(55 0)" stroke="none">Github</text>
                          </a>
                          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="110" y2="0"/>
                          <g transform="translate(110 0) rotate(120)">
                            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="120" y2="0"/>
                            <g transform="translate(120 0) rotate(120)">
                              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="130" y2="0"/>
                              <g transform="translate(130 0) rotate(120)">
                                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="140" y2="0"/>
                                <g transform="translate(140 0) rotate(120)">
                                  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="150" y2="0"/>
                                  <g transform="translate(150 0) rotate(120)">
                                    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="160" y2="0"/>
                                    <g transform="translate(160 0) rotate(120)">
                                      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="170" y2="0"/>
                                      <g transform="translate(170 0) rotate(120)">
                                        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="180" y2="0"/>
                                        <g transform="translate(180 0) rotate(120)">
                                          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="190" y2="0"/>
                                          <g transform="translate(190 0) rotate(120)">
                                            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="0"/>
                                            <g transform="translate(200 0) rotate(120)">
                                              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="210" y2="0"/>
                                            </g>
                                          </g>
                                        </g>
                                      </g>
                                    </g>
                                  </g>
                                </g>
                              </g>
                            </g>
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```